# Dynamic Yearly / Monthly Charts in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to create a dynamic line chart in Excel. The objective is to view a specific timeline inputted by the user. For example, if I want to view the first 12 months of data, the chart will show just 12 months. If I think a 36 month view would be more insightful, I can input a 36 and the chart automatically changes from 12 to 36 months.

Can anyone share some resources that will allow me to create this specific type of dynamically, changing chart?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question would be better-suited to Super User SE rather than Cross Validated, since it is asking "how to do X in Excel" rather than an underlying statistical issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **offset** formula in your chart references.

Look at this article in the "The dynamic formula method" section:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-build-dynamic-charts-in-excel/

Comment: It is good to include a crucial part of the linked solution in your answer. Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231), please. As for now your answer may be considered low-quality.